# Calculate latest date for every index with DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a dataset in Power BI like this

```
ID    DATE 
1  06/24/2016
1  06/24/2017
1  06/24/2018
2  08/08/2017
2  08/08/2016
3  12/12/2015
```

I would like to create a calculated column with DAX, in which i have to calculate the latest date for every index, but I am only able to get the latest date of all the dataset or the same date for every row.
The output should be this:

```
ID    DATE      MAXDATE
1  06/24/2016  06/24/2018
1  06/24/2017  06/24/2018
1  06/24/2018  06/24/2018
2  08/08/2017  08/08/2017
2  08/08/2016  08/08/2017
3  12/12/2015  12/12/2015
```

Comment: I guess there is a typo in your MAXDATE for your second line of ID=2

Comment: @Christoffer yup, I've corrected it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
MAXDATE = CALCULATE(MAX(Table1[Date]);FILTER(Table1;Table1[ID]=EARLIER(Table1[ID])))
```

Comment: Gives a syntax error. Should be , instead of ;  MAXDATE = CALCULATE(MAX(Table1[Date]),FILTER(Table1,Table1[ID]=EARLIER(Table1[ID])))

Comment: Depends on your region settings in Windows.